# S-Function Builder dynamically sized output

Tags: matlab, simulink

In the S-Function Builder block dialog, in the Output ports tab, I have set the Rows to -1 in order to have dynamically sized output. I have done the same for the Input ports.

The input will automatically fits with the input width fetched in Simulink.
What about the output ? How can I set the output port width in my C code ? I have tried the following function `ssSetNumOutputPorts` without success. In the Outputs tab, I wrote something like `y[30] = 99;`, but there is no error.(`y` being the output)

In Simulink, it shows the same port width(dimension) than the input's.

Comment: With no experience in the S-Function block, but a decent knowledge in MATLAB Coder, I guess that the C code provides a size variable as a 2-element array and a pointer to the matrix/vector. The size-variable defines how much to read in RAM and how to arrange that. At the first glance, it seems that you can specify this in the GUI but that you can either have a fixed-sized vector/matrix, a dynamic-sized vector or a matrix, which is sized dynamically *in both dimensions*, see [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/s-function-builder-dialog-box.html#f8-107355)